# Azure and TFS, how do I share my project with a new developer joining the team

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013

i'm trying to figure out what to do here

I have been building a project with VS 2013 and EF6 - with SQL Azure. I publish to Azure and my project sits in TFS so I can check in and out files

I have someone joining the team and it should be simple but i'm not sure how I can add another user to have rights to my TFS project folder and download the APP and away we go

Can someone point me in the right direction, i've looked in Azure Portal and tried clicking around in Solution Explorer in VS2013 to no avail

Comment: are you using TFS online? Or On-Premises TFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TFS Web Access click the little  cogwheel in the upper right corner to enter the admin area for your team project and navigate to the team, or from the home page of your Team Project click the "Manage All Team Members".

[image: Manage Team Members]

You can also get to this screen by clicking the Project Name in Team Explorer and opening the Settings. When connected to TFS 2012 or newer that should open the same admin pages.

[image]